# WARN Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0): TypeError: Cannot read property 'pick' of null TypeError: Cannot read property 'pick' of null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, promise

**I want to create an upload button using "react-native-document-picker" library where users allow to upload a pdf file. Unfortunately, when I try to press the upload button which is the touchable oppacity as shown on the code below the error I stated on the title starts to appeared and its not working as expected**

```
import React from "react";
import { TouchableOpacity, Alert, Text } from "react-native";
import DocumentPicker from "react-native-document-picker";
import { DocumentPickerResponse } from "react-native-document-picker";

const UploadButton = () => {
  const pickFile = async () => {
    try {
      const res: DocumentPickerResponse[] | null = await DocumentPicker.pick({
        type: [DocumentPicker.types.pdf],
      });

      if (res) {
        Alert.alert(
          "File Selected",
          `URI: ${res[0].uri}\nType: ${res[0].type}\nName: ${res[0].name}\nSize: ${res[0].size}`
        );
      }
    } catch (err) {
      if (DocumentPicker.isCancel(err)) {
        console.log("User cancelled the picker");
      } else {
        console.error("Error picking file:", err);
       // Handle the error gracefully, e.g., show an error message to the user.
       Alert.alert("Error", "An error occurred while picking the file.");
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={pickFile}>
      <Text>Upload</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};

export default UploadButton;
```

**Can someone please help to resolve this problem. Thanks**

Comment: What does `DocumentPicker` returns?

Comment: it returns nothing instead it shows on the console this error:  ERROR  Error picking file: [TypeError: Cannot read property 'pick' of null]

Comment: The error clearly indicates that `DocumentPicker` is `null`.

Comment: Did you tried `await new DocumentPicker.pick` ?